# Duvida : Busca com DropDownlist mvc 4 razor asp.net C# sql Server

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, razor

Estou tendo dificuldade em popular o dropdown com sql server, pois vem item repetidos do sql ... ex: quando eu seleciono as cidades ele vem com cidades repetidas e assim por diante, e nao consigo direcionar para pagina de busca.
segue o codigo

Controller Home:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        EDGSiteEntities op = new EDGSiteEntities();
        ViewBag.IdOperacao = new SelectList(op.Operacao, "IdOperacao", "Operacao1");
        EDGSiteEntities cid = new EDGSiteEntities();
        ViewBag.Cidade = new SelectList(cid.Cidade, "IdCidade", "Cidade1");

        return View(ResultadoBusca);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string IdOperacao,string Cidade)
    { 
    string operacao = IdOperacao;
    string operacaoRequest = Request["IdOperacao"];
    string cidade = Cidade;
    string cidadeRequest = Request["Cidade"];
    return View(ResultadoBusca);



    }

    private ActionResult View(Func<ActionResult> ResultadoBusca)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();

    }



    public ActionResult Institucional()
    {


        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult FaleConosco()
    {


        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult Home()
    {


        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult Imoveis()
    {


        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult Venda()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult Locação()
    {
         return View();
    }
    public ActionResult Consorcio()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult ResultadoBusca()
    {


        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult ImovelDetalhe()
    {


        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult Serviços()
    {


        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult Servicos_Locatario()
    {


        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult Servicos_Locador()
    {


        return View();
    }
```

pagina index

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

}
```

Busca rapida:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{  
   @Html.DropDownList("IdOperacao","Selecione")
   @Html.DropDownList("Cidade", "Selecione")
   <input Type="submit" value="Pesquisar" />
}
```

o que estou querendo fazer e uma busca por cidade e tipo de casa

Comment: O que você já tentou fazer? Coloca o código, fica mais fácil de te ajudar.

Comment: Poste o seu código! se puder estrutura da tabela e seu código no controller!

Comment: okay so um momento

Comment: Uma pergunta você é iniciante em MVC ASPNet com Entity?

Comment: sim sou iniciante em mvc mas em aspx conheço um pouco mais

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parece que tem erros conceituais:

No controller abaixo:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
        EDGSiteEntities op = new EDGSiteEntities();
        ViewBag.IdOperacao = new SelectList(op.Operacao, "IdOperacao", "Operacao1");
        EDGSiteEntities cid = new EDGSiteEntities();
        ViewBag.Cidade = new SelectList(cid.Cidade, "IdCidade", "Cidade1");

        return View(ResultadoBusca);
}
```

poderia ser resumido para:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
        EDGSiteEntities op = new EDGSiteEntities();
        ViewBag.IdOperacao = new SelectList(op.Operacao, "IdOperacao", "Operacao1");
        ViewBag.Cidade = new SelectList(op.Cidade.Distinct(), "IdCidade", "Cidade1");            

        return View(ResultadoBusca);
}
```

Tinha duas instâncias de `EDGSiteEntities`, só precisa de uma, e com ela tinha todas as informações para gerar os dados para sua `View`.Em Cidades poderia usar o comando `Distinct()` para não ter repetição de informação, mas, eu fiquei na duvida, porque, no Brasil existe cidades com o mesmo nome e estados diferentes, cabe ai um filtro por estado.

Eu não sei se o código por você está todo correto, fiz algumas alterações, e agora é testar no seu código.

Comment: mas e para Região de sp somente, será que eu preciso fazer uma dll e bll para redirecionar a para os produtos ?

Comment: Não, não esse o problema, poste na sua questão a tabela Cidade! e outra o codigo acima não deu certo?

Comment: sim, deu sim... obg @Virgilio